# How to know the size of the repos on a website link and also download it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, repository

I want to see the size of the repos and if they are okay to download in my laptop in case I don't have access to the internet.

[http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu)
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

In my laptop I can see the size of the particular file or path with `df -Th`, but how to check the size here?

Regards,
Tayto

Comment: You can download the ls-lR.gz file and do some addition?

Comment: This might be interesting: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors